# Using git on ruby with username and password

Tags: ruby, git, rake

I'm using the git gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/git) to deploy with rake and I'd like to authenticate using username and password.

I've looked but I can't find anything on the documentation relating to that (other than using ssh which I don't want to do).

Comment: What is the reason for using the git gem to deploy? Why not use the git command line tool?

Comment: At the moment that's the way the deployment is set. It's not possible to use the command line tool.